# Expecting an arithemetic operator in SAS?

Tags: sas

I got the following error:
[image]
I don't understand my error please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need space between do and _i_ (index variable) as shown below. as you have it as do_i_. your warning also gives a clue about this.

```
 data RV2;
  retain _seed_ 0;
 n=20;
 p=0.6;
 do _i_ = 1 to 100;
 binorm1= ranbin(_seed_,n, p);
output;
  end;
  drop _seed_ _i_;
run;
```

Comment: Yes that work! thank you! also where does the warning gave a clue?

Comment: WARNING: The variable _i_ in the DROP, KEEP, or RENAME list has never been referenced. which means your index variable never got created.